# Firebase webhook returning error when successful

Tags: angular, firebase, api, google-cloud-functions, angular-httpclient

I set up a webhook on Firebase, to create a user, that I call through my Angular app and even though the user gets successfully created it returns a error to my app. This is the first time I am trying this so I am still new to these methods.

**Firebase function:**

```
export const signUpUser = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    cors(request, response, () => {
        const data = request.query;
        admin.auth().createUser({
            email:data.email,
            emailVerified:false,
            password:data.password,
            displayName:data.name,
            disabled:false
        }).then((user) => {
            response.status(200).send(`Successfully created user ${user.displayName}`);
        }).catch((err) => {
            response.status(400).send("ERROR: " + err)
        })
    });
});
```

**Angular app function:**

```
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

testAPI(){
    let params = new HttpParams()
    .set('email', 'tes2t@test.com')
    .set('name', 'Tester2')
    .set('password', 'test123')

    this.http.get('https:somefake.url/signUpUser', {params:params}).subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data)
    }, error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
 }
```

**Message**

[image: Respone message]

As seen in the image, my response message sits in the error object and the message variable has a failure message.

I am not 100% sure how you send back responses as I am new to this, so general help and tips I would also appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I found my own problem, my webhook was returning type 'text' but the response type expected was 'json' .

So in the Angular app function I just added a extra field "responseType: 'text' " so it looks like:

{params:params, responseType:'text'}